# ASP.NET add item to array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this array defined:

```
string[] emailAddress = {};
```

What I am trying to do is add items to this array like so:

```
emailAddress[] = de.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
```

and I get a cannot convert string to array error. How do I add an item to an array?

Comment: Is using a `List<string>` an option?

Comment: Have you tried working with `List<string>` or even `ArrayList`?

Comment: I recommend you read this article on how to work with arrays in c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: List is not an option, has to be an array

Comment: Arrays are fixed sized collections. So once they are created you can't add or remove items.

Comment: @user979331 you can convert list to array anytime you want. But it's much easier to add/remove items from list. (actually you cannot change size of array. you can only create new array of different size)

Comment: @user979331 Why does it have to be an array?  Arrays are not meant for adding values as they are a fixed size.  You can always use Linq's `ToArray` if you need to create an array from a list for some reason.

Comment: What is `de.Properties` at all?

Comment: A tutorial on c# arrays will be of much greater benefit to you than this post. The page linked by @Igor is very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string[] emailAddress = new string[1]; // initialize it to a length of 1
emailAddress[0] = de.Properties["mail"][0].ToString(); // assign the string to position 1
```

If you do not know the length at runtime then use a generic List and convert it afterwards.

```
var emailAddress = new List<string>();
emailAddress.Add(de.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
var myArray = emailAddress.ToArray(); // create an array from the list
```

I recommend you read this article on how to work with arrays in c# (or some other tutorial).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize your array first with a fixed size:

```
string[] emailAddress = new string[5];  // array with 5 items
```

and then you can add items like this:

```
emailAddress[0] = de.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
```

But consider if somehow possible using a `List<string>` which is much more flexible.

Comment: `string[] emailAddress = {};` is valid initialization for array

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That is correct, but it is empty and as far as I know can't items be added to an empty array. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you are saying in answer that array has to be initialized, but OP already has initialized array. Your code works, but explanation is not correct :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy got it, updated my answer. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment that it **has to be** an array and can't be a List, this might be what you need.

Instantiate the array with a *specific length*.  Something like this

```
string[] emailAddress = new string[emailAddressde.Properties["mail"].Length];
```

Then you can loop through with something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < de.Properties["mail"].Length; i++)
    emailAddress[i] = de.Properties["mail"][i].ToString();
```

to populate your `emailAddress` array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference a location in your array, what you are trying to do is assign your value as the array.

```
emailAddress[0] = de.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: An Empty array wont have any items, this will throw an Exception because you acces the Item at Index 0.

Comment: That's correct but with the current declaration of the array this will result in an null reference exception

Answer (score 1):

If you know how big your array will be then you can init the array to a static size.  For example if you know that the array of email will only every be 2 items (index 0 and 1) then you can init the array to that size like this

string[] emailAddress = string[2];

if the items in the array are unknown (how many email addresses) the you should using something else like

List emailAddresses = new List();

So something like this:

```
List<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>();
emailAddresses.Add("youremail@mail.com");
emailAddresses.ToArray();
```